# CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'

Tags: node.js, discord.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYcdE.png)

i need help with that error when first coding discord bot
here code

```
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === "ping") {
    msg.reply("pong");
  }
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

i try many way on internet but it still not sold ;.;
pls help me
this is error

```
 throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
      ^

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (E:\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544:13)
    at new Client (E:\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:73:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\bot\src\bot.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is exactly what the error says it is; your client is missing intents. You need to specify what events and data your bot intends to work with (e.g. guild member presences, messages, etc).

> i try many way on internet but it still not sold

I don't know what tutorials or guides you're looking at, but only discord.js v11 and under can work without intents. Discord.js v12 and the latest version (v13) require intents to be specified. What intents you need to specify depends on what you want your bot to do. Does your bot need to detect messages and respond to them? Then enable the `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent. If your bot does not need to, for example, track guild member presences, you do not need to enable a `GUILD_PRESENCES` intent.

Before continuing, I would highly suggest you check out the official [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide) on how to create a bot on the latest version, which should have been the first place you looked for this information.

Here is a simple way to solve your issue based on the [code on that guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#creating-the-main-file), if you are using discord.js v13:

```js
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
```

Here is another way of doing it, if you are on discord.js v12 (this may also work in v13):

```js
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client } = require('discord.js');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"], ws: {intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"]} });
```

Note that the intents I specified in the above examples may not be enough for you, depending on what your bot is supposed to do in the future. But I believe those examples will be enough to get your current code working without the error you are experiencing.

For a full list of intents, check the discord developer docs [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents).

Comment: tks u a lot
i will try your way ;.;

Answer (score 0):

> To specify which events you want your bot to receive, first think about which events your bot needs to operate. Then select the required intents and add them to your client constructor, as shown below.
>
> All gateway intents, and the events belonging to each, are listed on the **[Discord API documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents)**. If you need your bot to receive messages (`MESSAGE_CREATE` - `"messageCreate"` in discord.js), you need the `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent. If you want your bot to post welcome messages for new members (`GUILD_MEMBER_ADD` - `"guildMemberAdd"` in discord.js), you need the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent, and so on.

Example:

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
    ]
});
```